# No changes to original dataframe after applying loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes such that

```
df_lst = [df1, df2]
```

I also created a function which removes the rows with '0' in the dataframe:

```
def dropzeros(df):
    newdf = df[df['x']!=0.0]
    return newdf
```

I tried applying this through a loop and placed an assignment variable within the loop, but the original dataframe remained unchanged even after running the loop.

```
for df in df_lst:
    df = dropzeros(df)
```

I also tried using list comprehensions to go about it

```
df_lst = [dropzeros(df) for df in df_lst]
```

I know the function works since when i apply print(len(df)) before and after the command dropzeros(df) there was a drop in the len, however, may I know how might I go about this problem such that my original dataframe is altered after running the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the variable `df` in your `for` loop does not *reference* a value in your list. You are creating a variable `df` afresh each iteration of your loop.

You can assign via [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) your function:

```
for idx, df in enumerate(df_lst):
    df_lst[idx] = df.pipe(dropzeros)
```